# Probabilistic interpretation of simulation

Tags: stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

I read a post on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441973/systematic-error-in-python-stochastic-simulation, and there's a part in the code that I'm having trouble understanding.

Within the code, there's a statement that if r > R, where R represents the probability of birth and r is a randomly drawn number, it suggests that a death occurred in the system. I'm confused about the rationale behind this interpretation. Can you help me, please?

Comment: I suggest asking the person who wrote that post, or at least asking on that site.  This really isn't a good site for code review.

Answer (score 1):

`r = np.random.random()` returns a (uniformly distributed) value $r \in [0,1)$.
If $R$ is the probability of birth, then if this random value is in $[0, R)$ the code adds a birth, and if it's in $[R, 1)$ then the code adds a death.

That is, the code is mimicking the process of performing lots of trials and trying to simulate randomness, since $r$ falls in $[0, R)$ with probability $R$ and in $[R, 1)$ with probability $1-R$.

Comment: That makes sense and my next question may be due to a lack of probabilistic knowledge. However, what is the logic behind claiming that the random value in that interval indicates a birth/death?

Comment: @RKerr The code simulates a trial which has probability $R$ of adding one to the population and probability $1-R$ of removing one from the population. $R$ is the probability of birth, so it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I believe I may not have articulated myself clearly. Let's consider the scenario where r = 0.5 and R = 0.7. The interval, in this case, is [0, 0.7), and r falls within it. However, I'm uncertain why this implies a birth. Could you elaborate on that, please?